# What are the ranges of each skill?

Tags: diablo-iii

A number of skills seem to have a max range which is never explicitly mentioned in the skill.  For example, when I cast Spirit Barrage, it will try to find a target near where I cast it, but will eventually stop if the target is too far away.  Or I will cast Acid Cloud at the edge of my screen, and it will appear closer to me than where I clicked.

When comparing the effectiveness of different skills, it would be very useful to know what the different ranges are.  Has anyone done the science to determine them?  Even a general "Short", "Medium", "Long" would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kudos again to the folks at diablo.incgamers.com for this information.  The results below are measured using in-game "yards".  See [this article](http://diablo.incgamers.com/blog/comments/diablo-iii-the-art-of-distance) for the details on how they did the measuring and an idea of what these distances look like on screen.  Note that these are based on beta, so if people see things that have changed (like Dire Bats being fixed), please update the values.

> **Maximum Distance/Range for Skills**
>
> A range of values is listed for a
>   few skills due to them being random. Also, distances for skills that
>   don’t touch the ground (& go past the left/right edge of the screen)
>   have their perspective affected by their casting elevation. I’m not
>   sure how to adjust the perceived distance to compensate, so their
>   actual range will be less than the observed distance listed. The
>   skills that are affected are marked with an “*”. Also, some skills
>   were harder than others to judge so there’s no guarantee it’s error
>   free.
>
> **Barbarian**
>
> 8 – Cleave (12 area effect)
>
> 10 – Bash
>
> 10 – Frenzy
>
> 11 – Revenge
>
> 12 – Rend
>
> 16 – Hammer of the Ancients (6 radius centered 10 yards in front
>   of the barb)
>
> 50 – Seismic Slam (possibly random)
>
> 50 – Leap
>
> 70* – Ancient Spear
>
> **Demon Hunter**
>
> 80* – Chakram (with a 3 radius)
>
> 80-90* – Rapid Fire (average due to being random)
>
> 85* – Bola Shot
>
> 86* – Impale
>
> 90* – Entangling Shot
>
> 100* – plain arrow
>
> 120-130* – Hungering Arrow (kind of> guessed here since it goes off screen)
>
> **Monk**
>
> 9 – Fists of Thunder (no rune, first 2 hits): third hit is 14
>   yards
>
> 10 – Crippling Wave
>
> 10 – Lashing Tail Kick
>
> 16 – Deadly Reach
>
> 27 – Wave of Light (initial area effect has radius of 16 centered 11
>   yards out from the monk)
>
> 28 – Fists of Thunder (with Thunderclap rune,teleport range); only 14 if not targeting
>
> 50 – Dashing Strike (only when cursor is close to a target, otherwise 10)
>
> **Witch Doctor**
>
> 30-50 – Plague of Toads (average due to being random)
>
> 30 – Firebats (no rune)
>
> 50 – Corpse Spiders (with random radius somewhere around 15 max)
>
> 60 – Grasp of the Dead (with 14 radius)
>
> 70* – Firebats (Direbats rune) : not the listed 40 (It’s been posted on the official
>   bug forum already.)
>
> 78* – Haunt (but when cursor is close to a target, it reaches all the way to the top corners)
>
> 100* – Poison Dart
>
> **Wizard**
>
> 14 – Spectral Blades (only 10 if not targeting)
>
> 20 – Frost Nova
>
> 20-30 – Shock Pulse (average due to being random)
>
> 26 – Wave of Force
>
> 50 – Arcane Torrent (with random radius about 8 yards, radius of 4
>   individually)
>
> 50 – Energy Twister (average due to being random) (with 8-10 radius)
>
> 55 – Ray of Frost
>
> 86* – Magic Missile
>
> 88* – plain wand missile
>
> 94* – Arcane Orb

Comment: What do the asterisks mean?

Comment: @Raven Brought over that part of the comment, it means skills where the range is affected by perspective, making it harder to measure.